# Update Image in react-native

Tags: react-native

I got stuck at a point,when i'm trying to Update the image or changed the image on button click in react-native.

Now,in my case my image get changed on button click and get update the state.
But when i go out of the app and open it again, my change image looks the same old image,

I can't see my update new image why this is happen?

what's the possible solution for that?

MY code snippet:

```
const image = require("./images/like_blue.png");
const image1 = require("./images/like.png");

    // so here i'm getting the image and in constructor
     this.state = {
          jsonURL2:'',
          likeImage:image1,
        };
```

Comment: This is because your state is not `persisted`, where are you getting the `image` from?

Comment: const image = require("./images/like_blue.png");
const image1 = require("./images/like.png");

// so here i'm getting the image and in constructor
 this.state = {
      jsonURL2:'',
      likeImage:image1,
    };

Comment: The state will always load the `image` you defined `initially`, since it is relative to component level, and on `refresh` it will go away, unless saved somewhere, perhaps in the [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html
)

Comment: i have no idea about AsyncStorage.can u pls elobrate me what are the steps for doing that??

Answer (score 1):

You have to use any AsyncStorage storage solution. First time your app loads up it always call that image which you set initial in the code. But once you use AsysncStorage then inside phone you can save a small piece of data like image name which should be call when App opens. Its just like client side storage. If you clear the app cache then that stored data will be vanished.

Comment: how to check . if first time load app?

Comment: The code you provided has set the state "likeImage:image1". So I think you are setting that state.